# QNIX Nvidia Display Issue with 331 Driver and 770

Tags: 13.10, nvidia, resolution, monitor

Upon trying to get my ubuntu 13.10 installation working on my new computer, I encountered an issue with the proprietary nvidia drivers and my display. Apparently, the two don't agree with each other (has to do with garbage EDID returned by the monitor).

I was very excited when I found the following blog post, which exactly described the problem I have been having and how to fix it:

http://blog.patshead.com/2013/09/linux-and-the-qnix-qx2710-monitor.html

I followed his directions exactly on how to configure my xorg.conf file, and the screen shows up. However, the right side of the screen is very dark and flickers--it seems as though the values are quite correct.

I have been struggling on how to proceed fixing this problem. It seem I need something different for the following line in my xorg.conf:

```
Modeline "2560x1440"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

Any assistance I could get I would be very grateful for.

Here's a pastebin of my current xorg.conf for reference: http://pastebin.com/7AMsDcAy

Answer (score 1):

Try using the -r option with cvt:

```
[~] cvt -r 2560 1440
# 2560x1440 59.95 Hz (CVT 3.69M9-R) hsync: 88.79 kHz; pclk: 241.50 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440R"  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync
```

Tried the same as you and screen was dark and had burn-in. Tried this and it finally works, Hooray!

The rest of my xorg.conf followed the blog you linked.

My setup:
GTX 750 ti
NVidia driver 340
Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I've been battling with this all day and finally found the cvt modeline method and then my monitor was dark and was burning in. I still have some burn in after rebooting however I expect that will fade away over time. I hope so anyway!

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't have burn in at all after modifying to the to output of cvt -r. Maybe you should try tweaking those settings some more.